# Unable to play uri using gst_element_make_from_uri

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I need to stream RTSP / HTTP stream and when I create an element source using `source = gst_element_make_from_uri();` it doesn't work. Has anybody used gstreamer for streaming RTSP / HTTP streams?

```
source   = gst_element_make_from_uri (GST_URI_SRC,"http://76.73.90.27:80/" ,NULL);
decoder = gst_element_factory_make ("mad",      "mad-decoder"); 
sink     = gst_element_factory_make ("alsasink", "audio-output");
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "location", argv[1], NULL);
gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
gst_object_unref (bus);

gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline),
                  source, decoder,sink, NULL);

gst_element_link_many (source, decoder, sink, NULL);

gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

g_main_loop_run (loop);
gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing at the wrong IP address. That IP is a normal web server, not streaming radio. Try playing the radio station's `.m3u` in a music player and see which address it actually plays.

Instead, try running `gst-launch souphttpsrc location=http://76.73.52.173/ ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink`. You can use `gst_parse_launch()` to use these same strings in your program, and your program will be much shorter.

Comment: Thanks. but using phonon i am unable to play .m3u / PLS files. Can u plz suggest how to play a playlist

Comment: @ruby I used winamp ; you might be able to use totem, vlc, or any other normal audio player. How do you normally listen to this radio station when you are not writing an application? .m3u is a very simple format. In your application, you just need to parse the station's playlist and attempt to open the next URL in the .m3u when you get an error or and end-of-stream.